# Can I run a bot inside a Django project that will run independently of other Django apps?

Tags: python, django, server, bots, django-apps

I have a Django project for a website. And for the same website, I run another Python bot to scrap some data. I was wondering if I could somehow attach the bot to the Django project so that both can run on the same server without causing harm to each other. The bot and other Django apps should run independently of each other.

Does anyone know how this can be done?

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Explain your use case, how bot is running, and how are you attaching your bot to django project, please add more details in the question.

Answer (score -1):

with the `multiprocessing` module I got a solution. In the `manage.py` file of a Django project, there's an `if` statement at the end that just calls the `main` function defined in the same file.

I created two processes using the `multiprocessing.Process` class. One for the `main` function and one for the bot I wanted to attach to the project. Then I started those processes and the bot was running as well as other apps of the Django project.

here's the code:

```
import multiprocessing

# A function to start the bot

def start_bot():
    ...

if __name__ == '__main__':
    bot_process = multiprocessing.Process(name='bot_process', target=start_bot)
    main_process = multiprocessing.Process(name='main_process', target=main)
    bot_process.start()
    main_process.start()
```

This is just a way of solving the problem. If you have a better solution please add an answer.

Comment: For production use this is a very bad approach. A uwsgi or similar daemon may start and stop Django processes at any given time, and you have the risk of killing the bot / launching multiple instances of it.